# How to power ESP32 with 230V AC

Tags: power, esp32, heat

I want to power ESP32 with 230V AC and I don’t know how to do it. The requirement is that it must never overheat. What components should i use? The ESP will be in small space with no airflow. Will it be even possible?

Comment: with an AC/DC switching power supply?

Comment: What do you mean "overheat"? The ESP32 is robust microcontroller, according to the datasheet, the board can work in a temperature range of -40 to +125 degrees Celsius. Do you think that your setup will get that hot?

Comment: And regarding the power, you can just use a standard 5V Wall adapter with a  voltage regulator

Comment: I’m not experienced with changing voltage and this kind of stuff, but I expexted it to produce quite a lot of heat. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, it generates very low heat. It gets a bit warm during Wifi operation, but even without any airflow in a tight container it will not get damaged.

Comment: Switched mode power supplies do not generate any major heat, and if your only load is the ESP32 then good luck trying to get anything hot

Comment: @Coder9390 thanks

Comment: I would just suggest standard USB chargers. They give you 5V and are very cheap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folks over at [Random Nerd Tutorials](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-hi-link-hlk-pm03/) offer a solution for this exact scenario using a [HLK-PM03](https://makeradvisor.com/tools/hi-link-hlk-pm03/) Hi-Link 100-240V AC to 3.3V 1A DC converter. They add electrical and thermal fuses to mitigate some of the possible failure modes of over-temperature or over-current.

The specifications of the HLK-PM03 are [here](http://www.hlktech.net/product_detail.php?ProId=59). I suspect there will be a few alternatives available that do a similar function.

My suggestion is to be hyper-aware of the safety issues of dealing with mains power, and to be realistic about your own capabilities.